# Listen for event and invoke callback, based on specification?

Tags: c#, events, callback

I am currently building out a custom task manager and I'm wondering if it's possible to tell the task manager to listen for a specific event (`OnSomething` below), and then invoke a callback method when the task raises that event. However, mentally I can't see how it's possible to listen for an event that doesn't exist at the base class level. For example, I have a base class that contains basic information about the task called `CustomTask`:

```
public abstract class CustomTask {
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; } = false;
    public void Start() {
        IsRunning = true;
        DoSomething();
        IsRunning = false;
    }
    protected abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

For the sake of SO readers, I've simplified the definition, but you get the gist of it. It contains basic details, a few methods for starting and canceling, provides basic state management (simplified `IsRunning` here), etc.

I then have custom tasks that derive from `CustomTask`, in this case, let's focus on a sample task called `CustomTaskA`. It contains a definition for an event called `OnSomething`, which someone, somewhere may want to listen for:

```
public sealed class CustomTaskA : CustomTask {
    protected override void DoSomething() => RaiseOnSomething(this, new EventArgs());
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnSomething;
    private void RaiseOnSomething(object sender, EventArgs e) => OnSomething?.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

Now, the `CustomTaskManager` registers tasks, tracks them via `Guid`, manages them and more, but for simplicity:

```
public sealed class CustomTaskManager {
    // Singleton setup.
    private static CustomTaskManager _instance = new CustomTaskManager();
    public static CustomTaskManager Instance {
        get {
            // Simplified for SO.
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new CustomTaskManager();

            return;
        }
    }

    // Collection of tasks.
    private Dictionary<Guid, CustomTask> _tasks = new Dictionary<Guid, CustomTask>();

    // Register and start a task.
    public bool TryRegisterAndStartTask(CustomTask task, out Guid taskId) {
        taskId = Guid.Empty;
        try {
            // Register task.
            taskId = Guid.NewGuid();
            _tasks.Add(taskId, task);

            // Listen for events.

            // Start task.
            task.Start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log exception.
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

When registering and starting a task, I'd like to tell the task manager I want to listen for `OnSomething`, and if `OnSomething` is invoked, I want the task manager to call a method `OnSomethingWasRaised`. For example:

```
TaskManager.Instance.TryRegisterAndStartTask(task, out Guid taskId, task.OnSomething, OnSomethingWasRaised);

private static void OnSomethingWasRaised(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Woohoo!");
}
```

I know the specifying and invoking a callback method is entirely possible, and listening for events is plausible with reflection.

---

Is there a way (with or without using reflection) to listen for a specified event defined on a derived object and then invoke a specified callback method?

**NOTE**: Please excuse any syntactical errors as I hand-typed the snippets to keep them minimal.

Comment: So why not just do task.OnSomething += OnSomethingWasRaised?

Comment: Does `CustomTaskManager` need to know this purely for internal purposes, or does it need to notify its consumers of the event?

Comment: @Evk because in order to do that, `CustomTaskManager` has to know the derived type `CustomTaskA` and it doesn't. It simply knows of `CustomTask` and it's defined events (and already utilizes them). Since `OnSomething` is defined in `CustomTaskA` and not in `CustomTask`, the `CustomTaskManager` has no knowledge of it.

Comment: @madreflection closer to the latter there. It would be very similar to notifying the consumer. Essentially, the consumer would tell `CustomTaskManager` what event to listen for, and what method to call when/if that event is raised.

Comment: TaskManager doesn't know that, but caller of TryRegisterAndStartTask. I meant first register task, then subscribe

Comment: @Evk I can and do, do that currently, just curious if it's possible to remove the subscribe and unsubscribe from the hands of the consumer. At this point it's more of a learning experience for me as I've had to move on to other code, but I'm still very curious about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with (proposed) approach like this:

```
TryRegisterAndStartTask(task, out Guid taskId, task.OnSomething, OnSomethingWasRaised);
```

is that you cannot pass event as argument, or store it in variable, because event is just a set of two methods (add and remove), just like property is a set of two methods get and set.

You can of course change event to "raw" delegate:

```
public EventHandler<EventArgs> OnSomething;
```

This one you can pass by reference:

```
public bool TryRegisterAndStartTask(CustomTask task, ref EventHandler<EventArgs> del, EventHandler<EventArgs> sub, out Guid taskId) {
        taskId = Guid.Empty;
        // subscribe
        del += sub;
        ...
} 

CustomTaskManager.Instance.TryRegisterAndStartTask(task, ref task.OnSomething, OnSomethingWasRaised, out var taskId);
```

But that's usually not a good idea, since you are losing private scope of events - with events one can only add\remove delegates, with raw delegate anyone can do anything, like invoking or setting to null.

If regular event stays - that means reflection is the only way to achieve your goal, and even worse - you'll have to reference to the event you want to subscribe to by string name, not by an actual reference, though you can use `nameof(task.OnSomething)`. Then, you are losing compile time validation of subscription delegate type. Say you want to subscribe to `event Action Something` but passing `Func<string>` delegate there. It will compile fine with reflection approach, and fail only at runtime.

Still if you insist that will look something like this:

```
public bool TryRegisterAndStartTask(CustomTask task, string eventName, Delegate sub, out Guid taskId) {
    taskId = Guid.Empty;
    // subscribe
    var ev = task.GetType().GetEvent(eventName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var addMethod = ev.GetAddMethod(); // this can be null or private by the way
    addMethod.Invoke(task, new [] {sub});
    ...
}
```

And called like this:

```
var task = new CustomTaskA();
EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = OnSomethingWasRaised;
CustomTaskManager.Instance.TryRegisterAndStartTask(task, nameof(task.OnSomething), handler, out var taskId);
```

Ugly, unsafe, and not worth it in your scenario, in my opinion.

Comment: Based on your counter arguments, I concur entirely. It was an interesting thought, but overall not a great idea. Thanks for this thorough answer!